# How to register UI Game Object for Native Advanced Ads Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, native-ads

I am integrating Native Advanced Ads for unity. I designed ads UI in canvas (UGUI). After designing UI registered UI Objects but they are not responding to clicks. How can I show native ads in unity ScrollView? any lead on this issue?

[Download Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fD0i_DoutCDc0VXfXLNis-Tzjl_eMVyE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you give some example code for what you have tried?

Comment: Ok let me upload it to drive.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fD0i_DoutCDc0VXfXLNis-Tzjl_eMVyE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Suggestion: If developers have api call to get URL of ad then there would be no issue on your end it would be developers responsibility to open ad on clicking the GameObject regardless of gameobject's space (2D/3D)

Comment: I think issue is with ray casting when we use UI GameObject with collider it register successfully but in SDK there is mechanism of Ray Cast that work only for world space not screen space objects.

Answer (score -1):

This Link could help you https://youtu.be/S9GLyuOeWOk 
but you have to set canvas to camera space and attached colliers and uncheck Raycast Target